# Duvida em formulario envolvendo select

Tags: php

Olá. Estou com uma duvida onde preciso pegar informações do usuario e mandar para o php. Não estou conseguindo pegar as informações de escolha do usuario.
Ele precisa escolher se é cliente ou funcionario nas opções. Queria saber se é possivel enviar essa informação, pois tenho uma tabela chamado cargo no banco onde guardo se o usuario é cliente ou funcionario.

**Formulario**

```
<form class="" method="post" action="controleUsuario.php">
        <h1 class=""><b>Cadastrar</b></h1>
        <div class="form-group"> <label for="nome">Nome:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome"> </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu Email"> </div>
        <div class="form-group"> <label for="senha">Senha:</label> <input type="password" class="form-control" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Digite sua senha"> </div>
        <label class="mr-sm-2 sr-only" for="escolha">Escolha:</label>
        <div class="form-row align-items-left">
        <div class="col-auto my-1">
  <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" name="escolha" id="escolha">
    <option name="cliente" id="cliente" value="Cliente">Cliente</option>
    <option name="funcionario" id="funcionario" value="Funcionario">Funcionario</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>

        <button type="submit" name="opcao" value="Cadastrar" class="btn btn-primary">Comfirmar</button>
      </form>
```

**controleUsuario**

```
if(isset($_POST["opcao"])){

$opcao = $_POST["opcao"];
$escolha = $_POST["escolha"];

if($opcao == "Cadastrar"){
    if($escolha=="Funcionario"){
    $funcionario=$_POST["funcionario"]; 
    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $senha =sha1($_POST["senha"]);
    cadastroFuncionario($nome,$email,$senha,$funcionario);
    header("Location: loginUsuario.php");
    }else if($escolha=="Cliente"){
    $cliente=$_POST["cliente"]; 
    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $senha =sha1($_POST["senha"]);
    cadastroCliente($nome,$email,$senha,$cliente);
    header("Location: loginUsuario.php");   
    }

}
```

Comment: Não entendi. $_POST["escolha"] funciona como deveria, mas o que você está tentando acessar com $_POST["funcionario"] e $_POST["cliente"]? Você não está enviando nada com esse nome, o que deveria ter nessas chaves?

Comment: Deveria ter. se ele for funcionario ele mandar "funcionario" para essa variavel

Comment: Por que você precisa de "funcionario" dentro de $_POST["funcionario"] se você já tem "funcionario" dentro de $_POST["escolha"]?

Comment: Poisé, isso me confundiu não tinha entendido direito esse negocio de $_POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As option são as distintas opções que um select tem, expressadas com a etiqueta `<OPTION>`

```
<select name="NOME" size="ALTURA">
<option value="VALOR A PASSAR">VALOR MOSTRADO</option>
<option value="VALOR A PASSAR">VALOR MOSTRADO</option>
<option value="VALOR A PASSAR" SELECTED>VALOR MOSTRADO</option>
</select>
```

**Atributos da tag option:**

- (value): Com este atributo, definimos a informação que cada item enviará ao servidor, caso o mesmo seja selecionado.
- (selected): Com este atributo, definimos entre os itens inseridos, qual aparecerá previamente selecionado.

> Não se usa name em `options`

```
    <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" name="escolha" id="escolha">
      <option name="cliente" id="cliente" value="Cliente">Cliente</option>
      <option name="funcionario" id="funcionario" value="Funcionario">Funcionario</option>
    </select>
```

> portanto, algo como `$funcionario=$_POST["funcionario"];` é inútil

Quando enviar o formulário para o PHP, o script responsável por receber as informações vai saber certinho o nome do formulário `"escolha"` e vai saber o valor que foi escolhido (`Cliente` ou `Funcionário`).

> O PHP vai recuperar o value do `option` marcado pelo `name` do select

No seu caso `$escolha = $_POST["escolha"];`